# UIPanGesture moves all views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to move a UIView on screen. I am using a `UIPanGesture` so that the view follows my finger on screen. I have also calculated various things to determine the speed of the gesture and based on that I animate the UIView out at that speed.

This works relatliy well - but it requires a touch on the actual UIView I want to move. I want to have the same effect by touching the main view and going a gesture that would only move that UIView and not all the views.

Here is the code that moves the UIView

```
-(void)dragging:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {

    self.panCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];


    }

CGPoint newCoord = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
float dX = newCoord.x-self.panCoord.x;


gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX, gesture.view.frame.origin.y, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);


if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

    methodEnd = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval executionTime = [methodEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:methodStart];


    double time = executionTime;

    float distance = start - end;


    int distanceOverTime = distance / time;
    float veloticty = distanceOverTime / 100;

    double miniTimeToUse = 0.5;
    double newMinTime;
    if (time < miniTimeToUse){

        newMinTime =  miniTimeToUse;
    }else {
        newMinTime = time;
    }

    NSLog (@"Distance: %f", distance);
    NSLog (@"X:%f", gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX);


    if (gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX >= 90 && distance >= 3){

        [UIView animateWithDuration:newMinTime
                              delay:0
             usingSpringWithDamping:0.9
              initialSpringVelocity:veloticty
                            options:0
                         animations:^{

                             self.filterView.frame = CGRectMake(300, 0, 300, 500);

                         } completion:nil];

    }
    if (gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX <= 181 ){

    [UIView animateWithDuration:newMinTime
    delay:0
    usingSpringWithDamping:0.9
    initialSpringVelocity:veloticty
    options:0
    animations:^{

        self.filterView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 0, 300, 500);

    } completion:nil];


    }
}
```

}

If I add the UIPangesture to the self.filteredView - it works okay. If I add it to the self.view - everything on screen moves.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line of code is going to move `self.view` if the gesture is attached to `self.view`

```
gesture.view.frame = CGRectMake(gesture.view.frame.origin.x+dX, gesture.view.frame.origin.y, gesture.view.frame.size.width, gesture.view.frame.size.height);
```

You might want to use `self.filteredView` there.

Comment: Still the same happens. Everything moves.

Comment: Did you change it in both places?  Also, I see many other places in the code that use `gesture.view`.  Every one of those needs to be reviewed to see if that makes sense given that `gesture.view` is now `self.view`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this method and you should set the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for your moveable view only.

```
-(void)moveView:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view.superview];

    recognizer.view.center = translation;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to get the same effect the eBay app has. If you look on their iOS app - once you have done a search, you slide your finger from right to left and a view appears on screen. It knows how slow / fast you swipe and works well. Am I taking the wrong approach to get this effect?